# How to Wrap RSA Private Key using AES on Lightweight API of Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

I have a `RSA` generate key using the `RSAKeyPairGenerator class`. It returns a `AsymmetricCipherKeyPair` with the keys in `AsymmetricKeyParameter` objects. `AsymmetricKeyParameter` don't have anyone encode function for get the key in a byte array.

The wrap function only receive `byte[]` parameter. How do I serialize the key using the Lightweight?

```
RSAKeyPairGenerator keyGenerator = new RSAKeyPairGenerator();
keyGenerator.init(new RSAKeyGenerationParameters(new BigInteger("10001" ,16), new SecureRandom(), 2048, 80));
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keys = keyGenerator.generateKeyPair();
AsymmetricKeyParameter priv = keys.getPrivate();
```

Comment: can you put some code please?

Comment: **I edit the post with the code**

With JCE I only use getEncoded() in RSAPrivateKey object. This code is for study purposes, I only need show the generated key and wrap it with AES, this is a example in the Beginning Cryptography with Java book.